# ConfigurationSection vs IConfigurationSectionHandler

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I want to use custom elements in my config.

When writing my custom configuration classes I used ConfigurationSection, but when my code tries to access the information from my custom config elements it throws an error stating that:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for XxxSection: Type 'Xxx' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'.

I was under the impression IConfigurationSectionHandler had been depreciated in .NET Framework 2.0 so was wondering if there are any circumstances that would lead to that error being thrown if my code is using .NET Framework 4.0, debugging through VS2013 on a Windows 8.1 64bit machine.

Most of the threads I have read that discuss these classes are several years old and were around the time when the depreciation of IConfigurationSectionHandler was still happening (was stated in some places but not documentation etc.) so there was confusion around it.

I would like to avoid reverting back to using depreciated interfaces if I can. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to work out what was wrong, the configSection at the top of the config file was set up incorrectly.  The type should always reference the class that inherits from ConfigurationSection:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="purgeDirectorySection" type="Foo.FooBarSection, Foo"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    ...
  </appSettings>
  <FooBarSection>
    ...
  </FooBarSection>
</configuration>
```

This now works for me.  Hope this helps others who may experience this problem.